# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'cvextern' or one of its dependencies. (libcvextern.so) Emgu.CV

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, emgucv

Any idea how to solve this issue?

I'm trying to deploy my project in an environment in Elastic Beanstalk AWS, Platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.16.8

When I run the project locally in a windows machine, it works properly, bu in server I get this error:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'cvextern' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libcvextern: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I already tried copying files directly in the project with "Copy always" property, but not luck.

This is my docker file:

#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY 
["ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker/ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker.csproj", "ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker/"]

RUN dotnet restore "ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker/ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker"

RUN dotnet build "ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev libx11-dev && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProcessingFaceDetection.Worker.dll"]
```

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Did you download the runtime library? See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1

Comment: It supposes to be in the docker container, the platform is already configured in the Elastic Beanstalk in AWS.

Comment: Is the docker dll in the same folder as the application you are running? Did you run the setup.exe on deploy machine?